# Search for files contain lines with many conditions

Tags: grep, text, find

I can search for files which have a specific word by using `grep`

```
grep -l "word" /path
```

However what if I want to search for files which have "word 1" and "word 2" in a same line? I can use:

```
mkdir new;for i in * do;grep "word 1" $i > new/$i_new;done
```

then use

```
grep -l "word 2" /new
```

But I would like to have a one line command. Using

```
egrep -w -R 'word 1|word 2' /path
```

only search for lines have "word 1" OR "word 2".

What if I have "word 3", "word 4"?

Comment: `grep -H word1 /path | grep word2 | grep word3 | grep word4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pipes to successively filter the lines, until you get what you want:
`grep word1 /path | grep word2 | grep word3 | grep word4`

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you had N words in lines? Then you have to use N piped `grep` commands?

```bsh
grep word1 /path | grep word2 | grep word3 | grep word4 | grep word5 | ... | grep wordN
```

Here is using only one `grep` and matching line if contains multiple words:

```bsh
grep -E 'word1.*word2.*word3.*word4.*' /path
```

Above command simulates AND using grep's `-E` option. This command will work if your words in line are in the same order and will fails if you had a line like below:

```
word4 and word3 and word2 and word1
```

#### So what is the new idea to working/finding the matches in any order?

The idea is using grep with `-P` (Perl-Compatibility) option and [lookahead regex `(?=(regex))`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```bsh
grep -P '(?=.*?word1)(?=.*?word2)(?=.*?word4)(?=.*?word3)' /path
```

- The `.*?` means matching every characters `.` that repeated zero or more times `*` while they are optional. The `?` makes everything optional before it (means zero or one time of everything matched `.*` )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the Perl-compatibility really let us use Perl in grep?

Comment: Not exactly but closely. see `man pcre`